# Which PageRank formula should I use?

Tags: pagerank

I see a lot of people using `PR(A) = 1 - d + d * \sigma PR(E)/L(E)` as the pagerank formula. But it's really `PR(A) = (1 - d)/N + \sigma PR(E)/L(E)`. I know there won't be that much a difference since if `PR(A) > PR(B)` then it's still the same whichever formula you use. Also in Larry Page's paper on PageRank he said that when added together all pageranks should equal 1

Comment: @Seth: yes. so which one should i use?

Answer (score 1):

If you want that all values sum up to one you should use the `(1-d)/n + d * sum(...)` version.